# Is it a good idea to close and open hibernate sessions frequently?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I'm developing an application which requires that state of entities be read from a database at frequent intervals or triggers. However, once hibernate reads the state, it doesn't re-read it unless I explicitly close the session and read the entity in a new session.

Is it a good idea to open a session everytime I want to read the entity and then close it afterwards? How much of an overhead does this put on the application and the database (we use a c3p0 connection pool also)?

Will it be enough to simply evict the entity from the session before reading it again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use `refresh` to reload the entity. Or `evict` and `clear`, as mentioned by @Bozho.

With a connection pool, the overhead to open and close session isn't big. What takes time is to construct the session factory.

The problem with closing and re-opening a session is that object already loaded will still become detached, if I remember well. This can be problematic w.r.t to lazy loading. So it's better to keep the session open and use `evict`, `clear` or `refresh`.

Note that if you evict the entity, and you access one such entity already loaded, you will still get the old data.

```
MyEntity e = session.load( ... );
...
session.evict(e);         // remove entity from the cache
String p = e.myProperty;  // still the value at the time it was loaded
e = sesssion.load( ... ); // latest value
```

In you case, it might be better to introduce a design guideline that says that anytime the entity is manipulated, it should be refreshed first.

```
MyEntity e = session.load( ... );
...
session.refresh( e );     // refresh entity and cache
String p = e.myProperty;  // latest value
e = sesssion.load( ... ); // latest value
```

The code above is only pseudo-code, I haven't checked it.

Note that if the session is opened for a certain time, the cache may grow, in which case you may want to still `clear` it. Generally speaking, it's however better to keep the session short to prevent this problem of cache growth, plus problems with connection timeout, transaction timeout, and lock contention.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. `evict()` the object. If you want to clear the entire session, `clear()` it.

A new session should be associated with either a request (thread) or a longer-running conversation.

Comment: Could you provide me some reference material to read up on about session association and it's costs? I've googled it without much luck.

Answer (score 0):

For columns that link to other tables, if you set the fetchtype to LAZY Hibernate won't load that data until it is explicitly asked for. This saves a lot of time.

A column in `Table` could be marked:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="other_table_id", nullable = false)
private OtherTable otherTable;
```

So, not until you do something like `Table.getOtherTable().getValue()` will the `OtherTable` be loaded into the session. So if you don't do something that, you also don't need to evict it.

Please note that this is pseudocodish and might look a little different for your program.